# MySQL Insert into Table C from Table A and Table B

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables.

```
A:
----
ID |
----
1 |
---
2 |
---
3 |
---

B: 
--------
config | 
--------
paid      |
-----------
dispatch  |
-----------
delivered |
```

what I want is I want to have insert values into Table C which is All values from Table A * Table B.

Then C should be

```
C:
-------------------
A.ID | B.config | Value
-------------------
1 | paid | True
2 | paid | True
3 | paid | True
1 | dispatch | True
2 | dispatch | True
3 | dispatch | True
1 | delivered | True
2 | delivered | True
3 | delivered | True
```

Now the question is Can I do it with Single Mysql statement or I have to write a script with nested **for** loops to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with a cross join:

```
INSERT INTO C (ID, config, Value)
SELECT a.ID, b.config, 'True'
FROM A a
INNER JOIN B b
```

An inner join in MySQL with no `ON` clause defaults to being a cross join, though we could also have used `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: Tim,  whats the difference between your Inner Join and...FROM A a, B b?